# External links not opening in jQtouch

Tags: javascript, html, jqtouch

I'm coding a web app for Document Managers using jQtouch and have made a 'Top Searches' part of it. You can see the whole thing at http://dl.dropbox.com/u/97184921/Project/index.html

The following code is supposed to show a unordered list (which it does) with the two items - onen linking to Google and the other to BBC as test websites. They should both have thumbnails and they are displayed, but it doesn't seem to send the user to either Google or BBC when the links are clicked. Can anyone help?

```
        <li><a href = "http://www.google.co.uk/"><img height = "20" width = "20" src = "images/search.png">google</a></li>
        <li><a href = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/"><img height = "20" width = "20" src = "images/search.png">bbc</a></li>
```

Comment: @MichalKlouda — Images are defined as EMPTY, they close themselves.

Comment: @Michal Klouda You do not close image tags, have you ever coded any html before?

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/xkB8M/ - try making a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Fabricio Matte Why won't you open the link to his project first?

Comment: @Miszy I did open the link. It wasn't working on my Nightly for some reason, just switched to Canary and it worked now. Anyway, I'm just recommending OP to make a SSCCE for the next questions, you usually get faster and better answers this way.

Comment: It's a good advice. Just there are so many people posting answers before they even read the code...

Comment: @Miszy linking to a whole site demonstrating the problem isn't the best practice on SO. This "wall of code" effect should be avoided as much as possible. Another problem is that it renders the question unusable for others in the future (thus making them "too localized").

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the [jqtouch site](http://www.jqtouch.com/preview/demos/main/#home) they suggest that you use `target="_blank"` when opening external links.

If you'd like to open the link in the same window, try `rel="external"`

[source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/jqtouch/9lN72k0fh30)

better [source](http://www.golen.net/blog/jqtouch-link-behaviors/) with more info

Comment: Where is the OP talking about JQTouch?

Comment: @JamWaffles Nowhere, but he's using it. Open the link before you comment.
http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/issues/detail?id=9

Comment: @Miszy I don't like clicking on random Dropbox links but yes, you're correct. The OP could've helped themselves so very much if they'd tagged their question with [tag:jqtouch] or explicitly stated that they were using it.

Comment: i much appreciate the help with target = "_blank" but that opens the links in a new window and i was wanting it to open in the same window?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be that your links are hooked by your javascript, and that the script to process the click is failing.

If you look in the javascript console in FIreBug you'll find errors like the following after you click on a link:

> OPTIONS http://www.google.co.uk/ 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery.js:19
>   XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.google.co.uk/. Origin http://dl.dropbox.com is not allowed by > Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

As @davehale23 suggests, adding `target="_blank"` to your links will fix the issue (again you can test this by tweaking one of the link elements in FireBug.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href = "http://www.google.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img height = "20" width = "20" src = "images/search.png">google</a></li>
<li><a href = "http://www.bbc.co.uk/" target="_blank"><img height = "20" width = "20" src = "images/search.png">bbc</a></li>
```

target="_blank" in the anchor tag opens a new page (or tab) rather than having it open in the current browser window. It's the best approach because the user doesn't have navigate away from your site and deal with caching issues if the user wants to go back to your site.

http://jsfiddle.net/UCnY3/

If you use google chrome's developer tool displays the error:

"Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options."

More info on X-Frame-Options can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

There are two possible values for X-Frame-Options:

> DENY The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site
>   attempting to do so.
>
> SAMEORIGIN The page can only be displayed in a
>   frame on the same origin as the page itself.
>
> In other words, if you
>   specify DENY, not only will attempts to load the page in a frame fail
>   when loaded from other sites, attempts to do so will fail when loaded
>   from the same site. On the other hand, if you specify SAMEORIGIN, you
>   can still use the page in a frame as long as the site including it in
>   a frame it is the same as the one serving the page.

Comment: I didn't read what the other people posted.. they posted before I was able to respond.. as soon as I posted my answer, more people were able to get to it before I did. Thank you for judging me though.. *sarcasm*

Comment: "I didn't read what the other people posted" just says it all.

Comment: no.. when I went to the question.. no one posted.. after I posted my answer.. 2 more posts came up, I did a demo on jsfiddler to prove the point, and I went to look up the link for X-Frame.

Comment: @Miszy this answer may be superfluous but you're too harsh in my opinion : taking time to build an answer without reading other answers happens.

Comment: I would have read the other answers if there were answers to begin with! It took me a while to post the answer after writing up everything. And when I realized someone already posted the answer, it was too late and I went to add more stuff about X-Frame options instead (which no one even mentioned yet)